Howto handle UnknownHostException error in Jenkins
I have a Jenkinsfile looks like this:
import jenkins.org.apache.commons.validator.routines.DomainValidator

pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage ('Validate actions') {
            steps {
                script {
                    env.TEST_FQDN = "fully.unexistent.tld"
                    env.TEST_IP = "1.2.3.4"
                    if (InetAddress.getByName(env.TEST_FQDN).address.collect { it & 0xFF }.join('.') == env.TEST_IP) {
                        echo "the fqdn is and points to ${env.TEST_IP}"
                    } else {
                        currentBuild.result = 'ABORTED'
                        error('the fqdn is valid but not points to ${env.TEST_IP}')
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

If the env.TEST_FQDN has a valid (resolvable) domain, then the test will run fine. If it points to env.TEST_IP then the if will be true. If not, then it will run into the else. But I would like to test it with a non existent domain as well. If I do, then I get an exception error at the end of the build:
...
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Also:   hudson.remoting.ProxyException: org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.actions.ErrorAction$ErrorId: 2fe8a515-f7e5-4555-ab09-85aee87243a3
hudson.remoting.ProxyException: java.net.UnknownHostException: fully.unexistent.tld: Name or service not known
    at java.base/java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$PlatformNameService.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:934)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1543)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$NameServiceAddresses.get(InetAddress.java:852)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1533)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1385)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1306)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getByName(InetAddress.java:1256)
    at java_net_InetAddress$getByName.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at PluginClassLoader for workflow-cps//com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.DefaultInvoker.methodCall(DefaultInvoker.java:20)
    at PluginClassLoader for workflow-cps//org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.LoggingInvoker.methodCall(LoggingInvoker.java:117)
    at varValidator.validateResolvedHostname(varValidator.groovy:35)
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:27)
    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
    at PluginClassLoader for workflow-cps//com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationGroup.methodCall(ContinuationGroup.java:90)
    at PluginClassLoader for workflow-cps//com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:116)
    at PluginClassLoader for workflow-cps//com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:85)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor284.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:569)
    at PluginClassLoader for workflow-cps//com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at PluginClassLoader for workflow-cps//com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.LocalVariableBlock$LocalVariable.get(LocalVariableBlock.java:39)
    at PluginClassLoader for workflow-cps//com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.LValueBlock$GetAdapter.receive(LValueBlock.java:30)
    at PluginClassLoader for workflow-cps//com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.LocalVariableBlock.evalLValue(LocalVariableBlock.java:28)
    at PluginClassLoader for workflow-cps//com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.LValueBlock$BlockImpl.eval(LValueBlock.java:55)
    at PluginClassLoader for workflow-cps//com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.LValueBlock.eval(LValueBlock.java:16)
    at PluginClassLoader for workflow-cps//com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:83)
    at PluginClassLoader for workflow-cps//com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:147)
    at PluginClassLoader for workflow-cps//org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$001(SandboxContinuable.java:17)
    at PluginClassLoader for workflow-cps//org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:49)
    at PluginClassLoader for workflow-cps//org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:180)
    at PluginClassLoader for workflow-cps//org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:422)
    at PluginClassLoader for workflow-cps//org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:330)
    at PluginClassLoader for workflow-cps//org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:294)
    at PluginClassLoader for workflow-cps//org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService.lambda$wrap$4(CpsVmExecutorService.java:140)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:139)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:68)
    at jenkins.util.ErrorLoggingExecutorService.lambda$wrap$0(ErrorLoggingExecutorService.java:51)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at PluginClassLoader for workflow-cps//org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$1.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:53)
    at PluginClassLoader for workflow-cps//org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$1.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:50)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:136)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:275)
    at PluginClassLoader for workflow-cps//org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService.lambda$categoryThreadFactory$0(CpsVmExecutorService.java:50)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
Finished: FAILURE

This is right, because that hostname does not exists.
What I would like to do:

Handle the UnknownHostException somehow, to handle non-existent FQDN.
Have another class to test hostname exists or not, what I can run before the resolve test. I tried already DomainValidator.getInstance().isValid(env.TEST_FQDN) but it will not work at all, because it will pass if the FQDN syntax is correct. Something built-in groovy/java would be the best, to have a platform independent test.


isValid() doesn't throw any exceptions and doesn't try to resolve the name. See the implementation. It checks the name against a regex, that's all. So you don't need to catch any exceptions, your original approach with if is perfectly valid. Look for a different command that initiates some network communication, or at least name resolution.
To check if the domain name can resolve to an IP without throwing exceptions you can use something like this:
def isResolvable(fqdn) {
    try {
        java.net.InetAddress.getByName(env.TEST_FQDN)
        return true
    } catch(java.net.UnknownHostException e) {
        return false
    }
}


That is the reason why I tried InetAddress.getByName(env.TEST_FQDN) in the first place. But it also throws UnknownHostException what I'm not able to catch by Jenkins. I didn't found any other Java class for this.

The first pipeline you provided doesn't throw. It generates under 20 lines of logs and no Jenkins errors. Show the repro and full logs.

Thank you, what you said is valid, because the first test passed. I had a second test what throw the exception, I didn't realized that, sorry. I updated the question with the exact same way as I test it now in a different pipeline, also attached the full error log. But the question is the same, I would like to validate somehow the hostname can be resolved or handle the UnknownHostException

Right, added an example to the answer.
